# How Do I merge 3 XML files into one xml using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

So I need to merge 3 xml files into one xml file using PHP. Im a little confused on how I can do that. Some guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

These are my 3 files that I need to combine:

**XML 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CD_LIST country="USA">
<CD>
  <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
</CD_LIST>
```

**XML 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CD_LIST country="UK UK UK">
<CD>
  <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Bonnie Tylor</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Gary More</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>This is US</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Gary Lee</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>12.20</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
</CD_LIST>
```

**XML 3**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CD_LIST country="AU AU">
<CD>
  <TITLE>Whispering Jack</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>John Farnham</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>AU</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY> Farnham's studio </COMPANY>
  <PRICE>22.00</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1986</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Innocent Eyes</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Delta Goodrem</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>AU</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY> Delta Goodrem studio </COMPANY>
  <PRICE>13.50</PRICE>
  <YEAR>2008</YEAR>
</CD>
</CD_LIST>
```

The final output must include this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: xml convert into array and then merge array

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You'll get better responses if you can provide code of what you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 1):

As there is a slight problem with simply trying to merge the documents in that each one has a document root with a different attribute...

```
<CD_LIST country="AU AU">
<CD_LIST country="UK UK UK">
<CD_LIST country="USA">
```

So there are two posibilities, one is to just create a new tag which sits above these and copy the full contents under this or the second is to just copy all of the CD elements under a new root element.

This code does the simple merge them together under a new root...

```
function mergeFile ( DOMDocument $target, $fileName )    {
    $source = new DOMDocument();
    $source->load($fileName);

    $import = $target->importNode($source->documentElement, true);
    $target->documentElement->appendChild($import);
}

$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><CD_LIST></CD_LIST>');
mergeFile($target, "NewFile.xml");
mergeFile($target, "NewFile1.xml");
mergeFile($target, "NewFile2.xml");

$target->save("out.xml");
```

creates a document like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CD_LIST>
    <CD_LIST country="USA">
        <CD>
            <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
            <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
            <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
            <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
            <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
            <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
        </CD>
    </CD_LIST>
    <CD_LIST country="UK UK UK">
        <CD>
```

The second options is...

```
function mergeFile2 ( DOMDocument $target, $fileName )    {
    $source = new DOMDocument();
    $source->load($fileName);

    foreach ( $source->getElementsByTagName("CD") as $cd )   {
        $import = $target->importNode($cd, true);
        $target->documentElement->appendChild($import);
    }
}

$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><CD_LIST></CD_LIST>');
mergeFile2($target, "NewFile.xml");
mergeFile2($target, "NewFile1.xml");
mergeFile2($target, "NewFile2.xml");

$target->save("out2.xml");
```

creates...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CD_LIST>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tylor</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
```